# How can i apply pagination to display 3 items per page

Tags: javascript, html, pagination

I have an list of items fetched as below:

```
<ul id="products" class="abcd" style="display: block;">
    <li class="productslist">item1</li>
    <li class="productslist">item2</li>
    <li class="productslist">item3</li>
    <li class="productslist">item4</li>
    <li class="productslist">item5</li>
    <li class="productslist">item6</li>
    <li class="productslist">item7</li>
    <li class="productslist">item8</li>
    <li class="productslist">item9</li>
    <li class="productslist">item10</li>
    <li class="productslist">item11</li>
    <li class="productslist">item12</li>
    <li class="productslist">item13</li>
</ul>
```

Now I need to display 3 items per page after applying pagination. Kindly help me with Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is quite broad, however considering that this solution is not a great solution for longer lists, the code below will help you understand what to do.

```js
const list = [...document.querySelectorAll('.productslist')];
let count = 0;
const items_per_page = 3;
const pagination_numbers_container = document.querySelector('.pagination-numbers');

const paginate = (p) => {
  
  hideAll();
   
  if(p === 'next') count += items_per_page;
  else if(p === 'previous') count -= items_per_page;
  else count = p;
 
  if(count < 0 ) count = 0;
  else if(count >= (list.length - items_per_page)) count = (list.length - items_per_page) + ((list.length+1) % items_per_page);
  
  for(let i = count; i < (count+items_per_page); i++) {
    if(list[i]) list[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
  
}


const paginateNumberClickHandler = (evt) => {
 const page = parseInt(evt.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-page'));
  paginate(page * items_per_page)
}

const createPaginationNumbers = () => {
  
  const total_pages_rest = list.length % items_per_page;
  const total_pages = (list.length / items_per_page);
  const pagination_numbers = [];
  pagination_numbers_container.innerHTML = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < total_pages; i++) {
    pagination_numbers_container.innerHTML += `<button data-page="${i}" class="pag">${i+1}</button>`;
  }
    
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.pag')].forEach( (p) => p.addEventListener('click', paginateNumberClickHandler ));
}

const hideAll = () => list.forEach( (l) => l.style.display = 'none');

const next = document.querySelector('.next');
const previous = document.querySelector('.previous');
next.addEventListener('click', (e) => paginate("next"));
previous.addEventListener('click', (e) => paginate("previous"));


paginate(0);
createPaginationNumbers();
```

```html
<ul id="products" class="abcd" style="display: block;">
<li class="productslist">item1</li>
<li class="productslist">item2</li>
<li class="productslist">item3</li>
<li class="productslist">item4</li>
<li class="productslist">item5</li>
<li class="productslist">item6</li>
<li class="productslist">item7</li>
<li class="productslist">item8</li>
<li class="productslist">item9</li>
<li class="productslist">item10</li>
<li class="productslist">item11</li>
<li class="productslist">item12</li>
<li class="productslist">item13</li>
</ul>
<div class="pagination-numbers">
  
</div>
<button class="previous">
Previous
</button>
<button class="next">
Next
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @gugateider , for the answer. it really helped me a lot to understand the logic. Now i am able to apply in my code.

Comment: only issue what i am facing is when keep on clicking on next button its showing up the first set once its reached the last set. Can you please help in that.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope you understand how the logic of paginating items.
Basically you just need to edit the `else if` conditional. 
I've updated the answer, take a look

Comment: i am trying to implement page numbering in between Previous and Next button but not able to repeat the numbering like 1 2 3, just wondering is it possible in above example?

Comment: Yes that is possible, you just need to make sure this list is not going to be too big and if thats the case, I would recommend you loading this data dynamically.

I've updated the answer according to your needs.

Comment: ,You are just Awesome!! helped me a lot. thank you so much. 
In above comment loading data dynamically you mean to load productlist dynamically or pagination numbers.?